# Apache Camel SOAP requests using camel route

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, camel-cxf

I want to make a SOAP request using apache camel routing. I have tried cxf, http4, netty4-http. Nothing is working. I want something like

```
    from("direct:start")
   .to(myEndpoint)//should make soap call
   .process(new Processor(){
    public void process(Exchange e){
    Log.debug(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());//Should print returned value
}
})
```

What I have tried includes

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
                    <route id="wsClient">
                                <from uri="direct:start" />
                                <to
                                    uri="cxf:bean:productServiceEndpoint" />
                            </route>
                        </camelContext>
                        <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="productServiceEndpoint"
                                address="http://www.webservicex.com/country.asmx" wsdlURL="http://www.webservicex.com/country.asmx?wsdl"  />
```

This says serviceClass required. I dont understand. I am consuming it. Why do I need service class?

Next:

```
from("direct:start")
.process(new Processor() {

                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            exchange.getOut().setBody(
                                    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">   <soap:Header/>   <soap:Body>      <web:GetCountries/>   </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

                        }

                    })
.to("http4://www.webservicex.com/country.asmx")
.process(new Processor(){

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(""+exchange.getExchangeId());
                System.out.println(""+exchange.getIn().getBody());
                System.out.println(""+exchange.getIn().getBody());

            }


            })
```

This and netty4-http does not generate anything.

Comment: Thanks. I went through them. I could not understand them. I am looking for     from("direct:start")
   .to(myEndpoint)//should make soap call
   .process(new Processor(){
    public void process(Exchange e){
    Log.debug(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());//Should print returned value
}
}) . So if someone has done it before, they can share their approach and I can go forward.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code so you write to the IN exchange and not OUT exchange.
from("direct:start")
.process(new Processor() {

```
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    **exchange.getIn()**.setBody(
                            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET\">   <soap:Header/>   <soap:Body>      <web:GetCountries/>   </soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
```